# Connecting mini USB VCC and GND to a power supply, and D+/D- to a SBC's USB headers

Tags: usb, wiring, sbc

I have USB powered device ([rtl-sdr dongle](https://www.rtl-sdr.com/buy-rtl-sdr-dvb-t-dongles/)) with a mini-USB port, that I want to connect a single board computer ([BalenaFin](https://www.balena.io/fin/)). The SBC has regular USB ports and a 4 pins USB 2.0 headers on it:

[image]

A different page in the SBC's datasheet lists the 4 pins' roles:

- VCC
- D-
- D+
- GND

I have a suspicion (based on [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/RTLSDR/comments/dgjgtx/rtl_test_on_raspberry_pi_losing_samples/)) that this SBC doesn't have enough drive to power my USB device via it's regular USB port. Hence I wired the device's VCC and GND sraight to my power supply, and connected only the D- and D+ wires to the USB header.

The Mini USB cable I took has 5 wires (including shielding) in it, which include the shielding. I connected it to the GND of the cable and then both of them to the power supply's GND, in addition to power supply's VCC.

I tested this setup and the device seems to be identified, but `libusb` gives read and write errors which I don't know how to interpret. Connecting the device to a regular USB port doesn't give *these* errors, but I do experience other issues (which led me to investigate this alternative wiring idea).

Is my wiring OK? Or is there something naive in it?

Comment: Did you connect the GND of the SBC to the GND of the power supply?

Comment: To the GND of the power supply.